# iisadmpwd Utility on IIS

Tags: iis

I need to make sure that users with expired passwords can change their password through this utility.

Is there a way to make my password expire and test it? 
I have the virtual directory configured for anonymous access, so that anyone can access the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace to manipulate user accounts to flexibly expire and refresh passwords programmatically.

I have successfully been able to expire users' passwords and then use the IISADMPWD pages to reset it.